# How to implement Pub-Sub Network with a Proxy by using XPUB and XSUB in ZeroMQ(C++)?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am a newcomer to zeromq. Recently I did some tests on pub/sub of zeromq, and I don't konw how to implement Pub-Sub Network with a Proxy by using XPUB and XSUB in ZeroMQ. Hope your help, thank you very much .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Proxy:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t frontend (context, ZMQ_XSUB);
    
    //set hwm...
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559");
    zmq::socket_t backend (context, ZMQ_XPUB);
    
    //set hwm...
    zmq_bind (backend, "tcp://*:5560");
    zmq_proxy (frontend, backend, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason I lost message is that I should have called setsockopt before bind or connect.

Refer to 0MQ API documentation for setsockopt:

Caution: All options, with the exception of ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE and ZMQ_LINGER, only take effect for subsequent socket bind/connects.

Answer (score 2):

Learn the basics by working through the [examples](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/C++). For the proxy, just use this, it's from [msgqueue.cpp](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C++/msgqueue.cpp)

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t frontend (context, ZMQ_XSUB);
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559");
    zmq::socket_t backend (context, ZMQ_XPUB);
    zmq_bind (backend, "tcp://*:5560");
    zmq_proxy (frontend, backend, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I also found anther problem. I started subscriber first, and then proxy, then publisher. In the publisher side, I sent 5000 * 2 KB messages, but in the subscriber side, I just received 951 * 2 KB messages. I wonder if this has something to do with "high-water mark" ? and what can I do for it ? Thanks.

Comment: That's a common problem, known as "slow subscriber". Even though you start subscriber first, some messages can be lost. You can avoid dropping messages by syncing subscriber with publisher before it sends, see this: https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/syncsub.cpp and this https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/syncpub.cpp

Comment: Yes, I did something to mark every message, and I found that what subscriber lost are the messages after 954, actually publisher have sent 5000 messages

Comment: I mean I have written "sleep()" some seconds in the publisher before it publishes messages

Comment: Just check the updated api, I got that example from zmq's own examples.

Comment: In the zmq v3.2, zmq.h, says, zmq_device() is the deprecated method. and messages still lost even I used zmq_device().

Comment: It seems to be useless.

Comment: I have done as you say. I started subscriber first, and then proxy, then publisher. In the publisher side, I sent 5000 * 2 KB messages, but in the subscriber side, I just received 951 * 2 KB messages. what subscriber lost are the messages after 951 , but actually publisher have sent 5000 messages .

Comment: Is there any API to unbind the socket and destroy the context in the zmq namespace?
I am seeing only zmq_unbind, zmq_close etc. functions from the zmq_... series.

Comment: @RupeshKumar  I believe those are the only ones

Comment: What's the difference between `frontend.bind(...)` and `zmq_bind(backend,...)`?